# Congratulations to @Paulster2 for hitting 50,000 reputation!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

## 50,000 Reputation

**Congratulations for your benchmark reputation hit!**

50,000 rep is not trivial.

I know you have contributed so much to this site and are emotionally invested in it's success.  You have really put in some serious time and effort into ensuring that.

I don't feel I have the experience to really thank you for what you have done here, I'll leave that to the real veterans.

All I can really do is thank you for welcoming me and helping me out with my multitude of questions.

**Again, congratulations!**

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Ducati ... I couldn't have gotten here without you :D I appreciate all the help you and everyone have given me in learning how to not be an A$$ while posting. It's been a fun 2+ years to get here. I wonder what the next 2+ years will bring.

Here's to a great site and internet friends! :D As I've said before, let's get everyone to 50k ... it's lonely up here!

Comment: The best grease monkey of us all :-)

Comment: @Anarach - LOL! I don't know that I'd go that far ... but thank you nonetheless :o)

Comment: I have two questions: Why your nick is in small caps? Why you appear after @DucatiKiller in the tab Users, ordered by reputation? Given yours is grater than him, shouldn't you appear in the first place?

Comment: @sergiol - I have small caps through [Small Caps Generator](http://fsymbols.com/generators/smallcaps/). I'm not sure what you're talking about as far as why Ducati would be first, unless you are looking at user reputation for the week, which [looking at it right now for the week](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) shows me well ahead of him ... Not sure what you mean.